# Facing some trouble in laravel query

Tags: laravel-5

I have two separate column startDate(yy-mm-dd) and startTime(24h).
Now I want    to fetch the records which are greater than now.
what is easy and efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

logically speaking, there shouldn't be records greater than now unless it is manually input or there is a serious issue with server time.

now if you want to check it, here is the code separately:

> whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear / whereTime
>
> The whereDate method may be used to compare a column's value against a date:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>', now())
                ->get();
```

> The whereTime method may be used to compare a column's value against a
>   specific time:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereTime('created_at', '>',now())
                ->get();
```

if you want them both together

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereColumn([
                ['startDate', '>', now()],
                ['startTime', '>', now()]
            ])->get();
```